# running phpmyadmin on centOS - forbidden error (403)

Tags: phpmyadmin, centos, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to install phpmyadmin and my phpmyadmin.conf is as follows:

Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin"
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
/Directory

(the tags are dropped only here)

Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
Alias /mysqladmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

I still get: "You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server."
this appears also when trying to approach as the localhost and also from the outside.
What can be done to fix it?
thanks.

Comment: What are the permissions on the folder. This usually occurs if you accidently give write permissions to anyone on the phpmyadmin folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the permissions to phpmyadmin folder recursively with

```
#chmod 755 /your/phpmyadmin/folder
```

and change the owner of the folder to www-data (or your webserver group user)